# ERROR One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: error

Here is the image with what happens when I try to reindex[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have forgot to add the add to you htaccess file.

AddType application/x-httpd-php76 .php

If this does not help then you need to check your php version should greater than 5.6.5

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more. I have to add that line AddType application/x-httpd-php76 .php to my htaccess file?

Comment: please clean cache and try to reindex again

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: have you edited \ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php

Comment: No. I just unzip the website, installed and now I'm having that error about indexes, but just with one of them 

Catalog Rule Product Indexed rule/product association 
UPDATE ON SAVE
REINDEX REQUIRED
Apr 24, 2017, 9:20:51 AM

Comment: ok can you upgrade once

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

and then deploy static content again
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I got the same error for every command I try... When installing magento, I didn't knew where to use the command composer install, could be that?

Comment: yes, may be that is the case..are you on localhost and wamp

Comment: Yes. localhost and wamp. win10

Comment: AbstractFactory.php line 93 is the culprit

    protected function createObject($type, $args)
    {
        return new $type(...array_values($args));
    }

Comment: Let me know if PHP has ...array_values() function now

Comment: It turns out that ... is a new operator introduced in PHP 5.6, which is also known as the Splat Operator.

Upgrading PHP version to 5.6 will solve the problem.

Comment: I had two php versions on my php folder. Was that the problem. I still have some other problems, but I guess I have to open new questions for them right?

Comment: can you create a new php file and print echo phpinfo();  ..to check the current php version

Comment: It is PHP Version: 5.6.25 now

Comment: did you get ...array_values() triple dots before array_value()

Comment: Yes. Now it's working, since I removed one of the php versions... My error now is about something else. I'm getting this message "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email" where it's supposed to show the menu and my products are also not being showed

Comment: ok can you vote and make the answer useful please..Thanks in Advance